# MailChimp API PHP - Add to Interest Group

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm currently using the MailChimp API for PHP, version 1.3.1 (http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/#php)

I've set up a list in MailChimp, and would like to dynamically add:

1. Subscribers to the list (done: `$objMailChimp->listBatchSubscribe($strMailingListID, ...)`)
2. Interest Groupings (done: `$objMailChimp->listInterestGroupingAdd($strMailingListID, ...)`)
3. Interest Groups into those Groupings (done: `$objMailChimp->listInterestGroupAdd($strMailingListID, ...)`)
4. Subscribers assigned to relevant Groups (not done)

The API (http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/#listrelated) is somewhat unclear on how to add a subscriber to an interest group - does anyone here have any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## For MailChimp API v3

> As of v3, 'groupings' has changed to 'interests'.

You have to find out the ID of the group (interest) that you are wanting to add to. Unfortunately this cannot be found anywhere on the MailChimp dashboard.

The easiest way to find out the 'interest' ID (rather than creating a script) is to go to the [MailChimp playground](https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/playground/) and then, after entering in your API key, route to...

> lists > the list in question > interest-categories (in the sub-resources dropdown)
>
> **then...**
>
> interests (in the sub-resources dropdown) for interest category
>
> **then...**
>
> Click through to the interest and refer to the 'id' field, ignoring the other ID fields

**OR**

> lists > the list in question > members (in the sub-resources dropdown)
>
> **then...**
>
> load (in the actions dropdown) for any member
>
> **or**
>
> Create Members (button)
>
> The page will load the member's details. Scroll down until you see the 'interests' array/object. There you will see the IDs. Notice they can be set to true or false.
>
> You will have to figure out which ID relates to what 'group'/'interest' by going about the previous method or making the call, and then looking at the member's details via your MailChimp dashboard.

---

So when it comes to actually making the **POST** call ('member' create), you would want something on the lines of...

```
{
  "email_address":"example@freddiesjokes.com",
  "status":"subscribed",
  "interests": {
    "b8a9d7cbf6": true,
    "5998e44916": false
  },
# ADDITIONAL FIELDS, IF REQUIRED...
  "merge_fields":{
    "FNAME": "foo bar",
    "LNAME": "foo bar",
    "MERGE3": "foo bar",
    "MERGE4": "foo bar"
  }
}
```

A **PUT** call ('member' edit) example...

```
{
  "interests": {
    "b8a9d7cbf6": false,
    "5998e44916": true
  }
}
```

> It seems that you must declare every 'interest', and state whether it is true or false.

Comment: I'm marking this as accepted since the API has moved on to v3. If you need the solution for v2, scroll down to Trevor Gehman's answer. Thanks for posting this, Crimbo

Comment: No problem! There is still no official documentation other than an [API guide](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/overview/). So you are left to guess what does what

Answer (score 21):

As of version 2.0 of MailChimp's API, this should work:

```
$merge_vars = array(
    'GROUPINGS' => array(
        array(
            'name' => "GROUP CATEGORY #1", // You can use either 'name' or 'id' to identify the group
            'groups' => array("GROUP NAME","GROUP NAME")
        ),
        array(
            'name' => "GROUP CATEGORY #2",
            'groups' => array("GROUP NAME")
        )
    )
);
```

Source: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php

Using a barebones PHP wrapper (https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/) you can then send this to MailChimp via either the lists/subscribe or lists/batch-subscribe:

```
$MailChimp = new MailChimp('API_KEY');
$result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
      'id'                => 'LIST ID',
      'email'             => array('email'=>'trevor@example.com'),
      'merge_vars'        => $merge_vars
));
```

Comment: Marking this one as correct so other people landing here see it. Thanks for posting the APIv2 version :)

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a comma in your array elements. I don't see any errors in the above code. Post yours and I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks @TrevorGehman, somehow I missed the whole dynamic of groups being inside groupings, this clarified it and got my subs working.

Comment: As the API has moved on to v3, I've unmarked this as correct, for the same reason as I originally accepted it :-) Thanks from everyone you've helped between then and now

Answer (score 8):

I could not get the other answers on this page to work. Here's the merge vars that I had to use:

```
$merge_vars = array(
    'GROUPINGS' => array(
        0 => array(
            'id' => "101", //You have to find the number via the API
            'groups' => "Interest Name 1, Interest Name 2",
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I had to find out what was meant by 'id' - it's the interest group LIST id. I'll post my code below.

Comment: Same here. The important thing is the array key within groupings. I spent about an hour on this until I found your answer. Sadly, the API didn't throw an exception otherwise.

Comment: Note that while you can pass 'name' or 'id' of the grouping list, you must only use the name (just as in the example) for 'groups'. It's unfortunate you cannot pass an ID there instead. :/

Comment: This is also the answer that worked for me. For me it was specifying the key "0" for the array inside 'GROUPINGS'

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUPINGS` merge var:

> Set Interest Groups by Grouping. Each element in this array should be
>   an array containing the "groups" parameter which contains a comma
>   delimited list of Interest Groups to add. Commas in Interest Group
>   names should be escaped with a backslash. ie, "," => "\," and either
>   an "id" or "name" parameter to specify the Grouping - get from
>   [listInterestGroupings()](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listinterestgroupings.func.php)

Comment: Which method is that available in?

Comment: Maybe this one http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listupdatemember.func.php ? ;)

Comment: Sorry, did not checked API for almost a year =)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code I got to work

```
require_once 'MCAPI.class.php';
require_once 'config.inc.php'; //contains apikey

// use this once to find out id of interest group List
//$retval = $api->listInterestGroupings($listId);
//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($retval);
//echo '</pre>';
//die();

$emailAddress = 'info@example.com';
//You have to find the number via the API (id of interest group list)
$interestGroupListId = FILLMEIN;

$api = new MCAPI($apikey);

// Create an array of Interest Groups you want to add the subscriber to.
$mergeVars = array(
    'GROUPINGS' => array(
        0 => array(
            'id' => $interestGroupListId, 
            'groups' => "FILL IN GROUP NAMES",
        )
    )
);

// Then use listUpdateMember to add them
$retval = $api->listUpdateMember($listId, $emailAddress, $mergeVars);

if ($api->errorCode){
    echo "Unable to update member info!\n";
    echo "\tCode=".$api->errorCode."\n";
    echo "\tMsg=".$api->errorMessage."\n";
} else {    
    echo "Returned: ".$retval."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation of Justins answer but having tried all the above this is the only one I could get to work with DrewM's MailChimp wrapper

```
$merge_vars = array(
    'GROUPINGS' => array(
        0 => array(
            'id' => '[GROUP_LIST_ID]', // need grouping ID
            'name' => '[OR_GROUP_LIST_NAME]', // or name instead
            'groups' => array( '[GROUP_NAME_1]', '[GROUP_NAME_2]' )
        )
    ),
);

$mc = new MailChimp('[YOUR_MAILCHIMP_API]');
$mc->call(
        'lists/subscribe', array(
            'id'                => '[YOUR_LIST_ID]', // list ID
            'email'             => array( 'email' => 'someone@something.com'),
            'merge_vars'        => $merge_vars,
            'double_optin'      => true,
            'update_existing'   => true,
            'replace_interests' => false, // do you want to add or replace?
            'send_welcome'      => false,
        )
    );
```

If you are unsure of your groups lists ID and wish to use it you can call:

```
$current_groupings = $mc->call( 'lists/interest-groupings', array(
                'id' => '[GROUP_LIST_ID]',
            ) );
var_dump($current_groupings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also please note optional but very important last parameter of listUpdateMember, by default **replace_interests** it set to true so it will overwrite any subscription the user you are updating could have had in the past. If you want to add new ones not touching previous ones just pass the new group name you wanna add and set **replace_interests** to false.

```
$api = new MailChimp('API_KEY');
$pArray = array('GROUPINGS'=>array(
                        array('name'=>'GROUP CATEGORY', 'groups'=>'group1,group2'),
                  )
    );
if (is_array($pArray)) {
        $api->listUpdateMember($pListId, $pEmail, $pArray, '', false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example using [DrewM's MailChimp wrapper](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/) and shorthand syntax for arrays (PHP 5.4+) [add to groups](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php):

```
$merge_vars = [
    'GROUPINGS' => array(
        0 => [
            'id' => 12345, // need grouping ID
            'name' => 'Interests', // or name instead
            'groups' => [ 'cars', 'trucks' ]
        ]
    ]
];

$mc = new MailChimp('API_KEY');
$mc->call(
        'lists/subscribe', [
            'id'                => '9876', // list ID
            'email'             => array[ 'email' => 'example@abc.com' ],
            'merge_vars'        => $merge_vars,
            'double_optin'      => true,
            'update_existing'   => true,
            'replace_interests' => false, // do you want to add or replace?
            'send_welcome'      => false,
        ]
    );
```

You need grouping 'name' **OR** 'id', both are not needed. To get grouping ID use: [lists/interest-groupings](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/interest-groupings.php)