# Add users to interest group via MailChimp API v2.0

Tags: php, api, mailchimp

I want to add a subscriber to an interest group via the MailChimp API.

This is my `$merge_vars` array:

```
$merge_vars = array(
    'GROUPINGS' => array(
        0 => array(
            'id' => 17385, // The group list ID
            'groups' => "Test 123", // A test group, that does exist
        )
    )
);
```

and this is how I'm updating the member:

```
$update = $mc->lists->updateMember(self::$mainListID, $email, $merge_vars);
```

Here's a `var_dump($merge_vars)`:

```
array(1) {
  ["GROUPINGS"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(17385)
      ["groups"]=>
      string(8) "Test 123"
    }
  }
}
```

and `$email` is a struct, here's `$var_dump($email)`:

```
array(1) {
  ["email"]=>
  string(11) "my@mail.com"
}
```

I'm about to be driven to distraction, because the API doesn't return an error, everything seems to go smoothly, except for the big problem of the user not being added to the list.

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761595/mailchimp-api-php-add-to-interest-group/8809708#8809708) which helped me get so far, but the version of the API it uses is 1.3 and that might have something to do with it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.

Although I could have *sworn* I'd already tried it this way... the groups have to be an array, even for a single group.

My code now:

```
$merge_vars = array(
    'GROUPINGS'=> array(
        array(
            'id' => 17385,
            'groups' => array($post['listName'])
        )
    )
);

$mc->lists->updateMember(self::$mainListID, $email, $merge_vars);
```

Works perfectly.

Comment: I am stuck with this too - but it looks to me like your question already had the groups as an array, with a single group inside.

Comment: Aah.  Ok, the list of group entries themselves should not be an array, they should be a comma delimited list.  I am surprised this worked.

Comment: Which version of the API are you using? It may have changed.

Comment: Thanks - you are right, I was using an old api - 1.3.

Comment: You should look into updating to the latest API, v2.0. I just updated a plugin that was using 1.3 to 2.0. It wasn't too difficult. It just involved updating the wrapper class we were using and re-writing a few functions.

Comment: $merge_vars = array(
    'GROUPINGS'=> array(
        array(
            'id' => 4541,
            'groups' => "$95 - Silver White, $95 - Gold Face"
        )
    )
);

$subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe( $list_id, array( 'email' => htmlentities($_POST['email']) ), array( 'ADDRESS' => implode('  ',$address)), $merge_vars );

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

For me works using **name** instead of **id** group.

```
$merge_vars = array(
    'groupings'=> array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Group Name',
            'groups' => array('Group item name')
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Sanaco

add this example for more checkboxes

```
$option1=$_POST['xxxx'];
$option2=$_POST['xxxx'];
$option3=$_POST['xxxx'];

'GROUPINGS'=> array(
                            array(
                                'id' => 123456,
                                'groups' => array($option1, $option2, $option3)
                            )
                        )
```