# Batch subscription with grouping mailchimp error

Tags: mailchimp

Hi guys i am using mailchimp 1.3 i used bactch subscription method but i face some problems by using this method the user subscribed in the list without group. But i want that the user subscribed with group the group name which i mentioned in my code (corporate). Here is my code

```
 $batch[] = array('EMAIL'=>$email, 'FNAME'=>$f_name,'LNAME'=>$l_name,'MMERGE4'=>$phone, 'MMERGE5'=> $title, 'GROUPINGS'=>array(

    array('name'=>'Members', 'groups'=>array('coporate'))

);

$vals = $api->listBatchSubscribe($list_id,$batch,$optin, $up_exist, $replace_int);
```

Thanks

Comment: error is that the user not subscribed to the particular group.

Comment: You groups array incorrectly uses "coporate". Is that in your code as well?

Comment: yeah .. the same array syntax i used in single subscription method "listSubscribe" there it is wroking and the user subscribed with exactly the same group ..

Comment: you can check it from here the grouping syntax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761595/mailchimp-api-php-add-to-interest-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I solved the issue here is the right syntax when used the batch subscription with grouping... Thanks

```
 $merge_vars = array('FNAME'=>$f_name, 'LNAME'=>$l_name, 'MMERGE4'=>$phone , 'MMERGE5'=> $title, 'GROUPINGS'=>array(
        array('name'=>'Members', 'groups'=>array('corporate'))  );

$batch[] = array('EMAIL'=>$email, $merge_vars);

$api->listBatchSubscribe($list_id,$batch,$optin, $up_exist, $replace_int);
```