# Add existing MailChimp subscriber to segment via email link

Tags: mailchimp, segment

I need to add an existing subscriber to a list segment via a link in a campaign email.

Been racking my brains over this for a little while and have a few ideas but was wondering if there is a more simple way.

My main idea at the moment is that they click a link and it takes them to a 'thank you' php page which automatically picks up a pushed email address and then adds that address to a segment.

Is this possible through merge tags or a different method?

Comment: Ok kind of answered my own question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28236254/1793797 using the thank you page method and a $email_address = $_GET["email"]; var